# Jfrog Xray API: are the violation filters broken or do I use them incorrectly

Tags: jfrog-xray

Im querying Xray 3.85.7 for violations for a specific artifact. According to the official [docs](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/violations) I should be able to filter on resources of type artifact.
But no matter what I try I always get back the same result set for altogether different artifacts.

I looked up the `manifest.json` in artifactory and used the repository path to derive my parameters.
After that I tried different variations for `repo` and `path` parameters without any changes in the results.
This is my query:

```bash
curl /api/v1/violations -H 'Content-Type: json' -X POST -d '{
  "filters": {
    "resources": {
      "artifacts": [
        {
          "repo": "my-docker-repo-local",
          "path": "my-awesome-image/1.0.0/manifest.json"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

The query is structured according to the docs.
If my parameters were wrong, I would expect an error or at least an empty result.

Any ideas?